# Background is not changing in pygame

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the user input and based off of user input, it runs the gameloop function. However, when the user presses the right key, it does not run the function or at least I do not think so. No errors are thrown. I am confused on why it will not work right now. I am running python 3.4.3. Also, I noticed that before the user input, I can't move the pygame window until after the user input. That tells me the function is working though. However, when I change the background of the gameloop function to blue, it does nothing either. So that tells me it is not working. I have no idea what is going on. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
import pygame
import math
import color
import sys
import random
import cx_Freeze
import time
import glob
pygame.init()
white=color.white
black=color.black
blue=color.blue
screen_width=800
screen_height=600
gamedisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Bingo Tracker')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
FPS=60
smallfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(screen_width/32))
mediumfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(screen_width/16))
largefont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(screen_width/10))
gamedisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
def intro_screen():
    start_message = mediumfont.render(str("Welcome to Bingo Tracker!!!"), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(start_message,(screen_width/5.614035088,screen_height/40))
    instructions=pygame.image.load('bingotrackerinstructions.png')
    gamedisplay.blit(instructions,(0,screen_height/8.053691275))
    pygame.display.update()
intro_screen()
def gameloop():
    gamedisplay.fill(white)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                quit()
    pygame.display.update()
instructionread=input("Press y to continue:")
instructionread=instructionread.lower
if instructionread=='y':
    gameloop()
```

Comment: Print `instructionread` just before comparision. It's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that gameloop is not being run is that you have missed the brackets from `instructionread=instructionread.lower()`

This means that instead `instructionread` being given the value "y" it gets the value of a `<built-in method lower of str object>`, so the `gameloop` doesn't run.

Note that `gameloop` has no loop (except the one that goes ones through the events). The procedure is run once, and then the program quits.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Darn brackets xd. Also, yes I know that it just have the quit function event, I am going to add to it. Anyone know why the window won't move until the user presses "y?" I got the while loop in there also, thanks for reminding me about that, I just forgot about that part.

Comment: Move the window, as in hold the title-bar and move it. That is something done by the operating system, not the program. I can move and hide the window, while the program flow is blocked by the input().

Comment: Ok, never mind about the window part then. I will just tell the user to move it after they put the "y" in.